# Is this an open or closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

> $S=\{5+\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \; : \; n \in \mathbb N\}$

According to my calculations this set has a lower bound of $4$ and an upperbound of $5$; however, since $4$ is reachable by the set it is a minimum and an infimum.  Since $5$ is the limit of the sequence it is not reachable and there is no maximum in the set, yet the supremum is $5$.

So I say the set is neither open nor closed and is the interval $[4,5)$

Is this correct?

Comment: Note that $5$ is not an upper bound. But $5.5$ is.

Comment: How do you claim that $S:=[4,5)$?

Comment: Yes, $5.5$ is max and sup. The reason that the set is not closed is that it contains points arbitrarily close to $5$ but does not contain $5$. The set $S$ is not anything like $[4,5)$ or $[4,5.5]$. These are *intervals*, while $S$ is a discrete set.

Comment: I've confused the record here by removing two empty-headed comments; I have *no* idea how I misread the description of the set so badly.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think I understand what you were saying.  I was confusing concepts.  However, the interval of my set $S$, $[4,5.5]$ is closed, right?

Comment: The interval $[4,5.5]$ is closed. Doesn't have a great deal to do with $S$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry for all the questions I'm just trying to understand.  If I follow your line of thinking, youre saying the interval I mentioned has nothing to do with my set because my set is not an interval.  It just contains elements of the given sequence.  So given that sequence of elements in the set, I have a minimum, infimum, supremum, and max that are in the set.  So my set is not actually open or closed.

Comment: @free_mind:  From the facts listed in your comment, one cannot yet conclude that $S$ is not closed. The reason it is not closed is that $5$ is a limit point of points in $S$, but $5$ is not in $S$. If we add $5$ to $S$ to make a new set $T$, the set $T$ will be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not closed since there is a sequence of elements in this set which converge to $5$, yet $5$ is not in this set.

Notice that it is also not open set. If $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open, then for every point in $x\in S$, there exists a ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\subset S$. This is clearly not true by taking $x = 4$.